# QUrl Class's *addQueryItem* method

Tags: qt, google-maps, qurl

I want to query the Google map for all the roads leading to a given GPS coordinate.

For that I'll have to place a "query" which can be done by: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qurl.html#addQueryItem

Now I want to know how to figure out that what should be the key and its corresponding value here?

Should the key be "road"/"roads"? Whats the way to decide that? And I want all the roads not a particular one!

Any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An HTTP URL has the following format:
http://some/address?key=value&more=values

The part behind the '?' is your query. You have to determine how the resulting URL should look like and add key/value pairs accordingly.

It isn't completely clear to me what you want to accomplish. You might want to check out these Google Maps API Links:

- http://code.google.com/intl/de/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Addresses
- http://code.google.com/intl/de/apis/maps/index.html

Comment: Thanks for answering, now, for example the url: http://maps.google.co.in/maps?hl=en&xhr=t&q=map+of+india&cp=7&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hq=&hnear=0x30635ff06b92b791:0xd78c4fa1854213a6,India&gl=in&ei=KsLQTcPZEuXq0gGbqoGVCw&sa=X&oi=geocode_result&ct=image&resnum=1&sqi=2&ved=0CCwQ8gEwAA . If you look at the first words after the "?", they are: _hl=en_. How to know what is hl here and what is en? What do they return?

Comment: and secondly, I want to accomplish this through Qt API instead of Google API.

Comment: The key/value pairs in the query string are defined by the website you are using. You therefore have to read the Google API documentation to find out which parameter means what.

Comment: Thanks thammi, after reading your last comment, I found this: http://mapki.com/wiki/Google_Map_Parameters Perhaps, this is what I needed :)